# AngularJS Proper way to pass variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to make them *global* so I can use `[color]` and `[shape]` throughout the whole script. I will need each one to update independently but as I continue to add to the site I am going to need to use both together.
[Live preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/sdE0mtVyBHXR7WoHQRFO?p=preview)

- Example does not work: `$scope.shapeSelected = response.data[color][shape];`
- Example does work: `$scope.shapeSelected = response.data.blue[shape];`

---

```
var app = angular.module("computer", ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/main', {
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/main'
    })
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.colorType = function(color) {
        $http.get('stuff.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.colorSelected = response.data.type[color];

        });
    }

    $scope.shapeType = function(shape) {
        $http.get('shapes.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.shapeSelected = response.data[color][shape]; // <--- [color] is not getting pulled in on this function.

            var resultsColorShape = $scope.shapeSelected; // <--- I would like to be able to store this incase i need it later. 
            console.log('resultsColorShape');
        });
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass argument to your functions. if you defined `ng-model="Color"` you can use `$scope.Color` in your javascript code:

change in html:

```
ng-change="colorType()"

ng-change="shapeType()"
```

and js to:

```
 $scope.colorType = function() {
 $http.get('stuff.json').then(function(response) {
     $scope.colorSelected = response.data.type[$scope.Color];

 });
}

 $scope.shapeType = function() {
     $http.get('shapes.json').then(function(response) {
         $scope.shapeSelected = response.data[$scope.Color][$scope.Shape]; 
     });
 }
```

Comment: Can you add this to the plnkr demo because I just tried using $scope.Color and $scope.Shape and neither works.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about passing the variables or sharing the data properly across functions then this should help you.

In your scenario. As the `ng-change` functions are assigned.

1. When the `ng-change` function is triggered if you don't have a `ng-model` try to save the new value that is the passed parameter in the `$scope` so as to access it across all the other functions in that controller.
2. If you have a `ng-model` declared for your element then just use the attribute for the ng-model as the reference variable . e.g: `ng-model="xyz"` then `$scope.xyz` would give you the desired value of the element.

This is how you can access the element value accordingly

Comment: Can you add this to the plnkr demo because I just tried using $scope.Color and $scope.Shape and neither works.